# How can I separate integer value from the following string in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

Let's say,
`String a="90 results";`

I need to extract the integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) should deal with this, although you could give us more information.

For example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(a);
scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the integer is always separated by space ,then you can split the string

```
String res[] = a.split(" ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(res[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "90 results";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
        if (!matcher.find())
            throw new NumberFormatException("For input string [" + str + "]");
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
    }
}
```